# Adding a DependencyProperty to a class that extends ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, observablecollection, dependencyobject

I have a class called `ObservableCollectionWithValidState` that serves to notify itself when an of it's child objects break a validation rule.

Class:

```
child
child  <== violated a passed in Predicate and is now invalid.
child
```

When this happens I would love to have a `DependencyProperty` on this class that I can set which can be bound to.

The problem is that my class extends `ObservableCollection<T>` but I can't see how to get `DependencyObject` into the picture.

I am pasting the initial declaration of the class along with an example of the property I would like to add (this will not work unless I can extend `DependencyProperty`).

```
public class ObservableCollectionWithIsValidState<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged,
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(ObservableCollectionWithIsValidState<T>), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    public bool IsValid
    {
       get { return (bool)GetValue(IsValidPropertyProperty); }
       set { SetValue(IsValidPropertyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

My two questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If it's not possible is there an alternate implementation you can suggest?

Comment: Unfortunatly you cannot derive from more than one base class, so I don't think this approch will work, perhaps you could just wrap your DependancyProperty and the collection in a new class that derives from Dependancy object and use the collection changed event to handle the validation. Not sure if this will work for your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. `DependencyProperty` can only be created in class that extends `DependencyObject`.

From [MSDN-DependendyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx)

> DependencyObject services and characteristics include the following:
>   Dependency property hosting support.
>
> - You register a dependency property by calling the Register method, and storing the method's return value as a public static field in your class.

---

> Is this possible?

Not Possible

> If it's not possible is there an alternate implementation you can suggest?

Use [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), and [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) with normal CLR property for Property validation. [Example](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/)

Comment: I ended up using INotifyPropertyChanged...would've been nice to have access to this as a dep prop but I made it work.